# Might laziness also mean a value of function depends on context where it is called?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm trying to learn Haskell, and whilst playing with applicative functors, one thing I found puzzles me.

Let's define following function *g* that returns some functor:

```
*Main> let g = pure (2*)
*Main> :t g
g :: (Num a, Applicative f) => f (a -> a)
```

Since a return type is **some** functor, I can use *g* as a parameter in both of these functions:

```
f1 :: (Num a) => [a -> a] -> a
f1 (g:[]) = g 3

f2 :: (Num a) => Maybe (a -> a) -> a
f2 (Just g) = g 4
```

But it means that a value the function *g* returns depends also on context in which will be evaluated! (It might be both List and Maybe.) Is this also a property of laziness? Because until now I was thinking about laziness in a way that a value is **calculated** when is needed, but it is already determined when it is defined (for *g* in *let* expression).

Comment: It's got nothing to do with laziness.  It's just regular overloading.

Comment: @augustss OK, now I know that also a single values can be overloaded in Haskell (so my example was unnecessarily complicated ;). But I still think this is somehow dependent on laziness. If the value wouldn't be evalueted when it's value is needed, it wouldn't be possible to overload it, right?

Comment: @MartinJiřička Values with a polymorphic type don't actually behave lazily - they behave like functions. That is they are evaluated every time you use them, rather than just the first time. So it doesn't work because of laziness (it wouldn't work with laziness), but rather because polymorphic values get special treatment compared to monomorphic ones.

Comment: I respond to myself: No, it is not about laziness, because it is not about when the value is calculated but which value is chosen (according the expected type). But now I find my original example with a function still a little bit different than this case.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, thank you. But one more question: why it wouldn't work with laziness?

Comment: Keep in mind that overloading is a compile time (static) feature and laziness is a runtime (dynamic) feature.

Comment: Also, the idea is that `g` really is some sort of closure (which is made explicit when I made it into a function from `Applicative f` to `f (a -> a)`) and, as such, it is *already* a value. The subtlety is that its argument gets picked at its use site by the compiler rather than the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @augustss said, it has nothing to do with laziness but rather the fact that you are working with a typeclass. To make this clearer, you can model typeclasses by explicitly passing along a record packing all the functions the class defines. This technique is called *dictionary passing* in case you want to look up more info about it.

We start with a few extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
```

And then give the record type packing the functions an `Applicative` is supposed to have (in practice you'd also have a field saying that `f` is a `Functor` but I omit it here for brevity).

```
data Applicative f =
  Applicative { pure :: forall a. a -> f a
              , app  :: forall a b. f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
              }
```

And we can define your function `g` as taking a record saying that `f` is an `Applicative` and delivering the behaviour you were describing (I kept `Num` as a class constraint but, similarly, it could be translated to record passing).

```
g :: Num a => Applicative f -> f (a -> a)
g Applicative{..} = pure (2*)
```

Your two functions `f1` and `f2` are still valid definitions:

```
f1 :: Num a => [a -> a] -> a
f1 (g:[]) = g 3

f2 :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a) -> a
f2 (Just g) = g 4
```

Now, we want to apply them to `g` but there's an issue: `g` has a function type expecting an `Applicative f` record being passed. Well, we can define the `[]` and `Maybe` instances of `Applicative`:

```
applicativeList :: Applicative []
applicativeList =
  Applicative { pure = (:[])
              , app  = \ fs as -> fs >>= \ f -> fmap f as
              }

applicativeMaybe :: Applicative Maybe
applicativeMaybe =
  Applicative { pure = Just
              , app  = \ fs as -> fs >>= \ f -> fmap f as
              }
```

And we then have to pick the right one for the application to typecheck (`[]` for `f1` and `Maybe` for `f2`):

```
f1g = f1 (g applicativeList)
f2g = f2 (g applicativeMaybe)
```

Comment: Whoa, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it is too complicated for me. Am I got it right that instead of "invisible" overloading of a function *pure* one can pass the "correct" version of the method explicitly to *g* via parameter, so it is visible that return value of *g* depends on expected type of the returned value?

Comment: That's the idea: instead of overloading, you can have what we call "dictionary passing" (a record containing the definitions of these overloaded operators).

Comment: Note that you need just `Rank2Types` not `RankNTypes` (at least in the case you have shown).

Comment: @gallais I am going to mark your answer as accepted. It would be great if you could extend your answer with the information about the "dictionary". I find it quite important notice and I think it should be in the answer and not only in a comment.

Comment: You're quite right. I've added a sentence to the introductory paragraph naming the technique used here.